# Using FileSaver.js in Safari damages download

Tags: javascript, svg, extjs, safari, filesaver.js

I'm using FileSaver.js to download an image on the client side using FileSaver.js. Works well in Chrome and IE11. But in Safari 11.1 (and I'll need support for 12+), the image (.png or .jpg) downloads but then won't open and the OS complains about the damaged file or unsupported file type.

My download looks like this:

```js
fileName = Ext.isIE || Ext.isSafari ? fileName + fileExtension : fileName;
saveAs(new Blob([file], { type: contentType }), fileName);
```

(saveAs doesn't add file extensions in IE11 or Safari, hence the addition of the fileExtension)

Anyway, file is an svg string and contentType is either "image/png" or "image/jpeg". I've also tried the following tweaks:
    appending ";charset=utf-8" to the contentType which doesn't help.
    prepending "data:" to create a dataURL, but I'm pretty sure that FileSaver.js is supposed to handle this.

I read that maybe there was a problem with checking if the browser is Safari in FileSaver.js so I went into the FileSaver.js source code and changed the check to Ext.isSafari (using ExtJs 6). Didn't help. I'm stumped.

Would appreciate any and all help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the issue was not with FileSaver.js. It wasn't even browser related, it was OS.

The issue was that I cannot just slap a .png or .jpg on an SVG blob and expect it to behave well. On windows (Chrome and IE11) the "conversion by extension change" worked fine, but Mac didn't accept it as legitimate and so rejected the file as corrupted.

I could recreate this by downloading the svg file with an .svg extension, see that it opened fine on Mac, and then change the extension to .png and see that I got the same error message. I guess Windows is just more forgiving.